# Create and bind queues dynamically to a single Exchange

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit

I have an exchange (`exchange1`) and it can be routed to `n` different queues based on routing-key-expression.

1. All Images messages should go to queue1
2. All Document messages should go to queue2
3. All video messages should go to default queue3

and in future, the queue number can be increased like (all video and mp4 extensions should go to `queue4`)

How we can create and bind queues dynamically to one particular exchange and should use only one stream Listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done directly with Spring Cloud Stream via properties.

You would have to declare `Exchange`, `Queue` and `Binding` `@Bean`s with the required routing keys and then configure the consumer binding to not declare the queue and binding) and then set `s.c.s.consumer.multiplex=true` and `s.c.s.destination=queue1,queue2,queue3`.

See [Using Existing Queues/Exhanges](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/3.0.6.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#_using_existing_queuesexchanges) for how to disable binder provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done using Spring-AMQP plugin in Spring boot. I have enclosed a below snippet how it can be achieved. (I believe code speaks more than theoritical words) :

```
package com.savk.workout.spring.rabbitmqconversendreceivefanoutproducer;

import org.springframework.amqp.core.*;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DynamicBindingDemo {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    private boolean switchedOn = true;

    //Toggle binding programatically
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 10000L)
    public void manipulateBinding() {
        Exchange exchange = ExchangeBuilder.directExchange("exchange").autoDelete().build();
        Queue queue = QueueBuilder.nonDurable("queue").build();
    
        Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with("routingkey").noargs();
        
        if(switchedOn) {
            rabbitAdmin.declareBinding(binding);
        } else {
            rabbitAdmin.removeBinding(binding);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin() {
        return new RabbitAdmin(rabbitTemplate.getConnectionFactory());
    }

}
```

Make sure you also have corresponding RabbitListener for it :

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "queuename")
@RabbitHandler
public String handle(String msg)  {
    System.out.println("RCVD :: " + msg);
    String response = "PONG { " + msg + " } from INSTANCE " + INSTANCE;
    return response;
}
```

You see everything can be done dynamically. All you need is to manipulate with bindings.